# umbraco macros in menu

Tags: html, xslt, umbraco

I created a macro for my menu on the left and it is ok.

I want to use the same macros for the menu to the right without creating another. 
 
What should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:Stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:call-template name="drawNodes">  
  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="drawNodes">    
  <ul>    
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root/node [string(data[@alias='posizione_menu']) = 'left']">

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">
          <li><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></li>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <li>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" title="Accedi a {@nodeName}">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&laquo;]]> </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
          </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </ul>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What language, what platform, please go into more detail.

Comment: Show the code of what you do.

Comment: <ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root/node [string(data 
[@alias='posizione_menu']) = 'left']">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">
<li><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></li>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<li><a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" title="Accedi a {@nodeName}">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&laquo;]]> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></a>
</li>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>

Comment: Reformatted your posting to makes XML code visible. This would still need further information and better tagging though.

Comment: should err on 
<xsl: for-each select = "$ currentPage / ancestor-or-self:: root / node [string (data 
[@ alias = 'posizione_menu']) = 'left'] "> 

calls in this way only the left menu, which I would call the right menu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a macro you can easily do so by inserting into the .NET masterpage where you want to reuse it.

If you want different XHTML markup depending if it is on the left and right please let me know so I can help you out further.

Warren :)